# argument after ** must be a mapping, not ChatPermissions

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

when I print an object :

```
print(permissions)
```

it has output like this :

```
{'can_send_messages': True, 'can_send_media_messages': True, 'can_send_polls': True, 'can_send_other_messages': True, 'can_add_web_page_previews': True, 'can_change_info': True, 'can_invite_users': True, 'can_pin_messages': True}
```

exactly like a mapping object
but when I try it as an argument like :

```
some_method(id, **permissions)
```

it gives error:

```
 argument after ** must be a mapping, not ChatPermissions
```

what's the problem and how I can fix it ?

Comment: The type `ChatPermissions` seems to be incompatible with the `**` mapping, even that it's print out *looks like* a dict.. Try to convert it to a dict first!

Comment: does it have an easy way to make it dic ?

Comment: To `toString()` method of `ChatPermissions` can create an output which looks like a mapping object. You can create a dictionnary from it with `d = eval(str(permissions))`.

Comment: @Raida that's not a good idea. It is better to construct the dict

Comment: @Raida That's a horrible solution. Better: `{k:v for k,v in permissions.items()}` if `ChatPermissions` supports `items()`.

Comment: How your object looks ?

Comment: @AnGG i give it from another module i dont know how it looks

Comment: @KlausD. why it's horrible?

Comment: @KlausD. @Tomerikoo, I agree it is better to construct the dictionary, but I don't know what a `ChatPermissions` is, what the supported methods are. I propose a solution with the information I have for the moment.

Comment: I would suggest you to change some_method to work with this type, its also looks a bit strange to do eval

Comment: @KlausD. {'ChatPermissions' object has no attribute 'items'
} it doesn't work

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if the OP actually posted that `permissions` seems to be from [`Telegram-bot`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/fc5844c13da3b3fb20bb2d0bfcdf1efb1a826ba6/telegram/chat.py#L41)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `ChatPermissions` is the class from the `telegram` library, then you can do this:

```py
some_method(id, **permissions.to_dict())
```

In general, you can also use `__dict__` to get a dictionary of an object's attributes:

```py
some_method(id, **permissions.__dict__)
```

According to the [source code](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/15268acb2729411ab8a64ef6127933b1d100c27d/telegram/base.py#L56), the `to_dict` method itself uses `__dict__`, but excludes some attributes (`bot` and those beginning with an underscore).

Comment: This works for me as well in FastAPI implementation

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most elegant solution, but a working one in this case:

```
import ast
some_method(id, **ast.literal_eval(str(permissions)))
```

The `toString()` method of a `ChatPermissions` looks like a dictionary, even if it is not a dictionary. Thus, we can use that to create a dictionary and then have a mapping object.